# How to add a column entry in an already existing MYSQL database table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a html page with a text field for email. When I enter an email ID I store it in the database. The database has 3 fields namely 'serial_no','coupon_code','email'. I already have 100 odd coupon codes stored. So basically I have serial numbers 1-100, coupon codes 1-100 and my email column is blank. I want to give every email a unique coupon code. So whenever I add an email in the text filed it should go into the database in the email column where the coupon codes are not assigned to any email.

I'm using this sql query:

```
for($n=1;$n<100;$n++)
{
    $sql1='Update tbl SET email="'.$email.'" WHERE email="" && sr = "'.$n.'" ';
}
```

But this is replacing all the row in the table.
How do I achieve what I what?

Comment: do u want to update the coupon codes based on email?

Comment: 100 coupon codes already exists in the table. I just want to assign every email id entered to a unique coupon code

Comment: Which is unique/primary key in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql1='Update tbl SET email="'.$email.'" WHERE serial_no=(SELECT t.serial_no FROM tbl t WHERE t.email IS NULL ORDER BY t.serial_no LIMIT 1)';
```

The inner subquery will give first serial number for which email field is empty. Then update that record with the email address you got from your form. So this will update only one record.

Comment: @Phantom what is the name for your table? Simply replace `tbl` in the above query with your table name.

Comment: okay done that. Now I'm getting this error: You can't specify target table 'tbl' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @Phantom You are right, table aliasing in the subquery is required here. Please try the updated query above.

Answer (score 0):

Use following query

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `email` = 'email_value'  WHERE `email` IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```

inside loop

it will update only one null value **email** record at each iteration